# Match data found in a query

Tags: vba, ms-access, compiler-errors, criteria, matching

I need to create a VBA code that computes whether the data in the query that I have created matches or not. I am finding it difficult to begin to write the code.

what I started doing is the following:

```
Private Sub Analyse_Click()
Dim row As Long
With Query("qry_test1").Range((qry_test1Range))

    For row = 1 To .rows.Count

    If .Cells(row, AccountingPeriodCol).Value Like AccountingPeriodCriteria

    Debug.Print .Cells(row, ValueCol)

   End If
End Sub
```

its wrong as the error wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment appears.

Could some please be so kind of explaining the problem please

Comment: You  are finding it difficult to begin to write the code?

Answer (score 0):

What you got in your code is Excel-VBA, apart from you replacing `Sheets("WorksheetName")` with `Query("qry_test1")`.

This won't work. For stuff like that, you want to use SQL.

1. Read a [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/) on the basic syntax.
2. `Create → Query Design → SQL View`.
3. Write your SQL. Somethin along the lines of

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM qry_Test 
   WHERE AccountingPeriod = 'your Criteria'`
   ```

   should do what you want.
4. Optionally, wrap that into VBA

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, really appreciate it :)